# D3.js chart responsive behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to set listener to change a chart width with jQuery, when window width changes:

```
// Get width of parent div with jQuery

var widthContainer = $( ".chart" ).parent().width();

//set margins
// margin conventions https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563

var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 40};
var width = widthContainer - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 211 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set chart dimensions

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// listener

function changeWidth(){
   widthContainer = $( ".chart" ).parent().width();
   width = widthContainer - margin.left - margin.right;
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  changeWidth();
  console.log(widthContainer);
});
```

The `changeWidth()` function change the `widthContainer` variable, but chart dimensions does not change. Why?

Here is a working codepen (lines 13 to 40):
http://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/LbRyWa?editors=0011

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current changeWidth() only calculates the new width. you need to set the new width to the element you want.
And you would also need to update your chart x-scale and redraw the charts.

Quick update to your codepen (i moved changeWidth and resize to the bottom plus adding redraw function).

```
var redraw = function(newWidth) {
  // update xscale
  escalax.range([0, newWidth]);
  d3.select('.xaxis').call(xAxis);
  deuda.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[1]));
    });
  recono.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[1]));
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[2]));
    });
  provee.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[1] + d[2]));
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[3]));
    });
  credito.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[1] + d[2] + d[3]));
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return rr(escalax(d[3]));
    });
}

function changeWidth() {
  widthContainer = $(".chart").parent().width();
  width = widthContainer - margin.left - margin.right;

  // update chart width
  d3.select('.chart')
    .attr('width', width);

  // redraw chart
  redraw(width);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  changeWidth();
  console.log(widthContainer);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbboQL?editors=1010

Comment: Minor fix (line 243): .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right);